# A more efficient route

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, variables, iteration

I have managed get the desired end result, however there must be a more efficient way to do this. Let me walk you through:

I have 100 columns of opinion data regarding 20 categories.

[image: This is what the data looks like]

In the image above HEALTH and JOB are 2 of the 20 categories. Candidates are asked to rank the personal importance of each category. They either Strongly Disagree (1), Disagree (2), No Opinion (3), Agree (4) or Strongly Agree (5).

What I want to happen is for a new column to be created for each category and to stack the values so there is one column with the candidates answers rather than being spread out over 5 columns. It has been predetermined that no candidate has given two answers for a category. The green columns in the picture above show the desired outcome.

Here is the inefficient route I have taken:

The data is a csv file read in using pandas.

I created a list for each category, so 20 lists:

```
df.columns
health = list([col for col in df.columns if 'HEALTH' in col])
job = list([col for col in df.columns if 'JOB' in col])
```

I then created 20 new columns in the data frame that takes the max value from columns in the associated list using code below.

```
df['HEALTH'] = df[health].max(axis=1)
df['JOB'] = df[job].max(axis=1)
```

The last step is to delete those 100 original columns and only have the 20 new individual columns with all of the candidates answers stacked.

This was done using the code below using a list of the original opinion columns:

```
df.drop(df[op_cols], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.info()
```

I am teaching myself python 2.7 so any advice/suggestions on how to make these steps more efficient would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, first off, `list([col for col in df.columns if 'HEALTH' in col])` is redundant; the list comprehension inside creates a `list`, then the `list` constructor takes that `list`, shallow copies it, returns a new `list`, and the original `list` is destroyed. Remove the `list()` around both listcomps, and let Python construct the `list` directly only once.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a reshape process using pandas' [wide_to_long()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/reshaping.html). You will need to set a numeric value, here being `key` for output. Of course, rename final columns (without underscore) and sort as needed by category:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'RESPID': [1,1,1,1,1],
                   'HEALTH_SD': [1,np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                   'HEALTH_D': [np.nan, 2, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                   'HEALTH_N': [np.nan, np.nan, 3, np.nan, np.nan],
                   'HEALTH_A': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 4, np.nan],
                   'HEALTH_SA': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5],
                   'JOB_SD': [1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                   'JOB_D': [np.nan, 3, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                   'JOB_N': [np.nan, np.nan, 2, np.nan, np.nan],
                   'JOB_A': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5, np.nan],
                   'JOB_SA': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 4]})
print df[['RESPID', 'HEALTH_SD', 'HEALTH_D', 'HEALTH_N', 'HEALTH_A', 'HEALTH_SA',
         'JOB_SD', 'JOB_D', 'JOB_N', 'JOB_A', 'JOB_SA']]
#   RESPID  HEALTH_SD  HEALTH_D  HEALTH_N  HEALTH_A  HEALTH_SA  JOB_SD  JOB_D  JOB_N  JOB_A  JOB_SA
#0       1          1       NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN       1    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
#1       1        NaN         2       NaN       NaN        NaN     NaN      3    NaN    NaN     NaN
#2       1        NaN       NaN         3       NaN        NaN     NaN    NaN      2    NaN     NaN
#3       1        NaN       NaN       NaN         4        NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN      5     NaN
#4       1        NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN          5     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN       4

df['KEY'] = 1
rdf = pd.wide_to_long(df, ['HEALTH_', 'JOB_'], i='RESPID', j='CATEG').dropna().reset_index()    
print rdf

#   RESPID CATEG  KEY  HEALTH_  JOB_
#0       1     A    1        4     5
#1       1     D    1        2     3
#2       1     N    1        3     2
#3       1    SA    1        5     4
#4       1    SD    1        1     1
```